# wordpress blog in a subdirectory of the magento root folder

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, nginx

I have a Magento site at http://example.com and I want to keep a Wordpress blog at http://example.com/blog. I have installed the blog and everything seems to be fine but when am logging to Wp-Admin am getting 404 for css and js files.

My configuration below link:-

https://serverfault.com/questions/594841/magento-wordpress-nginx-configuration

Comment: I know this is a while back but could you outline the steps you took to do this? I'm about to install WP on a Magento site too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set your site/home URL correctly?

Also in `wp-config.php`, make sure to set your `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` variables to the correct URL (subdirectory) you are using

It should look like this:

```
$host = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/blog/';
define('WP_HOME',$host);
define('WP_SITEURL',$host);
```